# How do I setup the Product Planning Workbook in TFS (Scrum Template)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, scrum

I'm using the Scrum Template in TFS.  I have a SharePoint portal associated with my project.

Unfortunately, I cannot find the Product Planning Workbook. I thought it was supposed to show up magically in the Shared Documents section of the Team Project but Shared Documents is blank.

Did I mess up something during configuration or am I supposed to do something now?

I'm using VS2010 Ultimate and TFS 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The planning workbook is not in the scrum template. You can upload the workbook with the following instructions [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150806234405/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/aaronbjork/archive/2010/03/16/unbound-agile-workbooks.aspx).

To have the workbook available for future use, you can [add it to the process template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/process-templates/define-project-portal-plug-in?view=tfs-2018&viewFallbackFrom=vsts).

I have never used this workbook with the Scrum template, so I don't know whether it will work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, the planning workbook is not the easiest path to turn TFS into scrum. This is why Microsoft did not include the planning workbook in the scrum template. If you want to add a premier scrum tooling to the Scrum Template, I suggest that you use Urban Turtle http://urbanturtle.com
send me feedback at ddanis@pyxis-tech.com